# Error:'vi: No terminal database found', while running vi from screen session

Tags: vi, freebsd, gnu-screen

I am unable to open a file with `vi` within a `screen` session. I am getting `vi: No terminal database found` while trying to open the file with vi.

```
$ which vi
/usr/bin/vi
$ /usr/bin/vi
vi: No terminal database found
```

I am able to open file using `vi` while I am disconnected from screen session.The below commands outside screen session works fine.

```
$ vi
$ vi a.txt
```

Tried workaround from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51760987/revisions) but I am getting `No matching processes were found` error

```
killall vi
No matching processes were found
```

Comment: Check whether your termcap or terminfo contains an entry for terminal type "screen". Command: infocmp screen

Comment: try `export TERM=xterm` just a wild guess

Comment: Questions about the FreeBSD operating system should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ This is not a programming question. Please delete this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nbari mentioned in the comments:

In the machine that you are sshing from, add this to your shell rc file:

1. `export TERM=xterm`.
2. Do: `source ~/.bashrc` or whatever shell you are using

NOTE: These steps are not to be done on the problem machine, but the freebsd you are sshing from.

Comment: Hello from Citrix :)